# Hexchat connects and drops repeatedly... new user, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: hexchat

It goes through a bunch of text over and over again, ending in this:

```
"   Version: TLSv1/SSLv3, cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256 bits)
* Connected. Now logging in.
* *** Looking up your hostname...
* *** Checking Ident
* *** Found your hostname
* *** No Ident response
* Capabilities supported: account-notify away-notify cap-notify chghost extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl tls
* Capabilities requested: account-notify away-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix 
* Capabilities acknowledged: account-notify away-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix 
* *** Notice -- You need to identify via SASL to use this server
* Closing Link: 140.sub-174-216-25.myvzw.com (SASL access only)
* Disconnected (Remote host closed socket)"
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed directions from two linux sites and also the help tab of hexchat, and what they say to do does not result in what they say will result. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, nor the `hexchat` you are using (is it the default package? have you changed it? or installed a snapped version?)

Comment: Looks like you need SASL configured to access the server, can you give details of which server and channel you are trying to access? Solution may very well be here: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/hexchat

Comment: Thank you, I have Ubuntu 16 installed on a laptop. Hexchat is 2.10.2, I haven't changed it in any way--wouldn't know how.

I tried instructions very similar to the ones you posted, andrew.46. But I don't have a username password, nor can I figure out how to set one. I also don't know any channels to access besides Ubuntu servers (freenode). Is it like email, do I need an address to connect? Thank you.